# Wordpress editor spacing very unreliable

Tags: editor

Firstly I apologize for the vague question.

But Im wondering can someone help. I have been developing on WordPress for approximately 2 years now, and I have yet to come up with a reliable solid solution for content editing.

The editor just seems unreliable and irritating to use. Its fine for me as Im a developer so I can put in whatever html code I like, but once the client takes over the site issues start to arise.

My main issue is with spacing, sometimes it decides to save the spacing , sometimes not.

I tell the client to put in two spaces to get a line break, and then a gap. This works fine, but then they may go back to it later and make another change and they'll have lost all their original spacing.

My other issue is that I dont know how it knows when to put in `<p>` tags. I wish it just left them out entirely, or put them in every time someone pressed return and started a new line.

Im wondering can anyone offer their opinion on the above, and/or offer a recommended editor that may be easy to integrate with Wordpress and Ill write a plugin myself.

Either that or suggest a very up to date plugin that is a much cleaner editor and that is definitely working on the latest version of WP. (Currently 3.9.1 but that shouldnt matter)

Thank you for the help.